# unexpected result when running twice than once

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption, password-encryption

this piece of code does return the right answer whenever i run it once on the right crypting key, but if i run it twice it gives completely different result

```
int key = Int32.Parse(MinKeyTB.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
CR = new Crypto(key);
textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
foreach (string temp in (ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(CR.Decrypt(ToBurtal))).Split('\n'))
{
    textBox3.Text += temp + Environment.NewLine;
}
key++;
MinKeyTB.Text = (key).ToString("X");
```

the min key textbox is where i type the key to be used, the right key is 1234 which works fine but if i ran it twice with 1233 then 1234 it gives a completely wrong answer

key is local variable (should not cause a problem)
CR is a custom class type which i reference it with new to a new object (should not cause a problem)
i clean textbox3 everytime before display (should not cause a problem)
ToBurtal is global byte[] which doesn't get modified anywhere in the application

any idea ? thanks and have a wonderful day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `ToBurtal` is getting modified inside the `Decrypt` function. Try it with a local copy of the array and see if that fixes your issue:

```
byte[] ToBurtalTemp = new byte[ToBurtal.Length];
Array.Copy(ToBurtal, ToBurtalTemp, ToBurtal.Length);

foreach (string temp in (ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(CR.Decrypt(ToBurtalTemp))).Split('\n'))
// etc.
```